# Click listener on smartsupp

Tags: javascript, smartsupp

I want to add an event listener click on `smartsupp`.
I have only this thing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var _smartsupp = _smartsupp || {};
        _smartsupp.key = 'f*****************89';
        window.smartsupp||(function(d) {
            var s,c,o=smartsupp=function(){ o._.push(arguments)};o._=[];
            s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];c=d.createElement('script');
            c.type='text/javascript';c.charset='utf-8';c.async=true;
            c.src='https://www.smartsuppchat.com/loader.js?';s.parentNode.insertBefore(c,s);

        })(document);

        smartsupp('language','<?php echo Yii::app()->language ?>');
    </script>
```

On which element should I set `addEventListener` or how can I do it in a proper way?
All what I want it's a click on smartsupp box and when it opens I get a `console.log("OPENED")`